# Crystal report login failed in server, but working fine in my system

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have created crystal report in asp.net vb Code, its working fine but when I changed the location of a solution or uploaded to a server its asking for data-set data-source connection..

In crystal report datasource connection I have choose "myconnection" in path:

> c:/user/...../.xsd

...

```
Dim Address As New DataTable
Dim Address1 As New DataTable
Dim Address2 As New DataTable
Dim Address3 As New DataTable
Dim Address4 As New DataTable
Dim crptConsOut As New CrystalReport2()
Dim dsCustomers As New DS_OTHER()

crptConsOut.Load("C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xxxx\Transaction\CrystalReport2.rpt")
crptConsOut.SetDataSource(dsCustomers)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crptConsOut
```

[image: Click Here For Screenshot],
[image: Click Here For Screenshot]
[image]

Comment: share your code and errors if any

Comment: You should share your code in text, not image

Comment: Dim Address As New DataTable
        Dim Address1 As New DataTable
        Dim Address2 As New DataTable
        Dim Address3 As New DataTable
        Dim Address4 As New DataTable
        Dim crptConsOut As New CrystalReport2()
        Dim dsCustomers As New DS_OTHER()

Comment: crptConsOut.Load("C:\Users\anand.kn.DIMEXON\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DIBS_PM(1)\Transaction\CrystalReport2.rpt")
        crptConsOut.SetDataSource(dsCustomers)       CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crptConsOut

Answer (score 0):

Please try loading the report document in ReportDocument before setting the Data Source. As in your local development machine report path is already set, but at server that may not load because of path mismatch. Also ensure that Folder has required permission to Read & Execute Report.

So as per your code before the line crptConsOut.SetDataSource Load the Report Document Using crptConsOut.Load("AbsoluteReportPath")

Ex.

```
crptConsOut.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
crptConsOut.Load("D:\ServerFolder\Reports\Customers.rpt");
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691449(v=vs.71).aspx

Note: Please use Parameters to bind query. Yuur queries are prone vulnerable, Please check this link for your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: thanks for your response Mr.Vishal Monpara , But That's Not Worked Out For Me, because i used strongly typed for crystal report , i tried but same error came..

Comment: crystal report loading correctly  after that , i am getting one dialog box like  "The report you requested requires further information."   DS_OTHER
Server name:  DS_OTHER
Database name:  
User name:  
Password:  
Use Integrated Security  Log On    "  But DS_OTHER is not server name its dataset name...,by default im getting servername : DS_OTHERS....

Comment: i create a new data set in another machine or in master copy its working, but  its showing same problem when it published and uploaded in IIS...   Please Help me ,I almost spent two days to resolve this issue....

Comment: try swapping 
crptConsOut.Load("D:\ServerFolder\Reports\Customers.rpt"); crptConsOut.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);

Comment: not working, thanks for your response Mr.Vishal Monpara , i have changed entire report moved to rdlc , rdlc working good..,thank you.